# Resetting composer classmap without install or update?

Tags: php, composer-php

Hi I was wondering if there is another way to reset the composer classmap back to its original state after running:

`composer dump-autoload -o`

After is has been optimized the classmap points directly to the classes it needs, and I know it can be reset with `composer install` or `composer update` but these commands have other side-effects.

Is there a command to just reset the classmap generated by the optimize flag?

**Edit**

Found composer dump-autoload seems that does the trick.

Comment: Have you try:  
--classmap-authoritative (-a): Autoload classes from the classmap only. Implicitly enables --optimize-autoloader

Comment: @mochalygin that is something entirely different than resetting the classmap back to its original state.